# ajax query based on model form sends no data to server

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms

I have a model based form:

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = ['comments_text']
```

In html:

```
<form action="" method="post" id = "comment_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}    
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Добавить комментарий" id = "add_comment">
</form>
```

When making an ajax query to add comment, it sends no input data from the form to view:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#comment_form").submit(function(e){

          $.ajax({
            url: url_,
            type: "post",
            success: function(result){
                alert(result);
            }
          });
    });
});
```

What's the reason? Console error: `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/addcomment/1/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: Have you defined `commentText`?

Comment: is it necessary to pass data? Or server can just take input from form?

Comment: When I defined commentText, why form.is_valid() returns false?

Comment: Try adding `return false` to the bottom of your `submit` handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When making an ajax query to add comment, it sends no input data from the form to view:

If you're using ajax, you'll need to pass the parameters manually through `data`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url_,
    type: "post",
    data: $('#comment_form').serialize(),
    success: function(result){
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

> What's the reason? Console error: POST `http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/addcomment/1/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Try leaving out the `url` parameter in your ajax request

Comment: Can I not pass data to view? Because, when I use it without ajax query, I don't pass data, django understands it: form = CommentForm(request.POST)

Comment: Ajax doesn't know about your form. That's why you need to explicitly pass it. I updated my answer.